# How to copy perf graphs from one user to another in datastax OpsCenter?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I have lots of perf graphs in datastax OpsCenter under my "admin" user.

I've created a new read-only user that i can let anyone in the company use, but how do i copy all the already configured perf graphs from the existing user into the new?

Is there a cql statement i can run in the "OpsCenter" keyspace?

Answer (score 1):

As of OpsCenter 5.0 there is a "Share with all users" option for each configured Dashboard.  You can use this to have that dashboard show up for all users.

If you're interested in only copying to a specific user you can use the OpsCenter API documented here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/api/docs/ui.html#ui